# Read line x of string?

Tags: python

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [get nth line of string in python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11491835/get-nth-line-of-string-in-python)

Is there a way to get a specified line from a multiline string in Python? For example:

```
>>> someString = 'Hello\nthere\npeople\nof\nEarth'
>>> aNewString = someString.line(1)
>>> print aNewString
there
```

I'd like to make a simple "interpreter" style script, looping through every line of the file it's fed.

Comment: [`str.split`](http://docs.python.org/library/stdtypes.html#str.split) and/or [`str.splitlines`](http://docs.python.org/library/stdtypes.html#str.splitlines)

Comment: Actually, if you want to make a simple interpreter, you probably don't want to get a string full of newlines in the first place. Instead of `script = scriptfile.read(); …; for line in lines:` just do `for line in scriptfile:`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
>>> someString = 'Hello\nthere\npeople\nof\nEarth'
>>> someList = someString.splitlines()
>>> aNewString = someList[1]
>>> print aNewString
there
```

Comment: Cool. I'm embarrassed to say I didn't know about `splitlines`.  Thanks.

Comment: @JohnVinyard: Then I'm guessing you've never written code on Unix and then had to deal with bugs from Windows users? I first discovered it after writing code to remove a `'\r'` from the end of each line if present… and then code to deal with a rare case where there was a real `'\r'` in just one line from a Unix text file… and…

Answer (score 2):

Remember that we can [`split`](http://docs.python.org/library/stdtypes.html#str.split) strings to form [lists](http://docs.python.org/tutorial/datastructures.html). In this case, you want to split using the newline character `\n` as your delimiter, so something like this:

```
someString = 'Hello\nthere\npeople\nof\nEarth'
print someString.split('\n')[lineindex]
```

There is also a [`splitlines`](http://docs.python.org/library/stdtypes.html#str.splitlines) function that uses universal newlines as delimiters:

```
someString = 'Hello\nthere\npeople\nof\nEarth'
print someString.splitlines()[lineindex]
```

Comment: `splitlines` does _not_ automatically use `'\n'` as a delimiter; it uses universal newlines. That's the whole point of using it instead.

Comment: @abarnert so it will work with any encoding on any platform?

Comment: Line endings are a different issue from encodings. It will work with Unix (\n), DOS/Windows (\r\n), or classic Mac (\r) line endings, using the exact same magic the interpreter uses everywhere else it deals with them. If the files are in UTF-16 or EBCDIC or something, it won't help; for that you have to use a codec (or just `somestring = somebytes.decode('UTF-16')`, and then you can deal with the line splitting.

Answer (score 2):

Split the string on newlines:

```
>>> someString = 'Hello\nthere\npeople\nof\nEarth'
>>> someString.split('\n')
['Hello', 'there', 'people', 'of', 'Earth']
>>> someString.split('\n')[1]
'there'
```

Answer (score 1):

```
In [109]: someString = 'Hello\nthere\npeople\nof\nEarth'

In [110]: someString.split("\n")[1]
Out[110]: 'there'

In [111]: lines=someString.split("\n")

In [112]: lines
Out[112]: ['Hello', 'there', 'people', 'of', 'Earth']
```